# Make a table of contents specific to appendix (article class) and display "Appendices" as a section in main TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I'm writing a document with `article` class and I compile it with TexMaker/pdfLatex.

I want to create a local table of contents for the `\appendix` but I don't want `\section{}` and `\subsection{}` written after `\appendix` to be displayed inside the main table of contents.

Here are some screenshots to explain my issue. My code is below the 2 following pictures.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[left=1.7cm,right=1.8cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=1.7cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[total={210mm,297mm},left=23mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%%%glossary%%%%
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\makeglossaries
%%acronyms commands%%\\
\newacronym{mof}{MOF}{Metal-oragnic framework}
\newacronym{lmof}{LMOF}{Luminescent metal-oragnic framework}
\newacronym{ln-mof}{Ln-MOF}{Lanthanide-based metal-oragnic framework}
\newacronym{ln-salt}{Ln-S}{Lanthanide salt}
\newacronym{ln-ox}{Ln-Ox}{Lanthanide oxide}
\newacronym{t-14-chdca}{t-1,4-cHdCA}{trans-1,4-cyclohexane dicarboxylic acid}
\newacronym{4444-pyrene-tetrabenzoic-acid}{H4TBAPy}{4,4',4'',4'''-(pyrene-1,3,6,8-tetrayl)tetrabenzoic acid}
\newacronym{dmf}{DMF}{Dimethylformamide}
\newacronym{h-ac}{HAc}{Acetic acid}
\newacronym{voc}{VOC}{Volatile organic compound}
\newacronym{xrd}{XRD}{X-ray diffraction}
\newacronym{pxrd}{PXRD}{Powder X-ray diffraction}
\newacronym{tga}{TGA}{Thermogravimetric analysis}
\newacronym{sem}{SEM}{Scanning electron microscopy}
\newacronym{gs}{GS}{Gas sorption}
\newacronym{uv-vis-fluo-spectro}{UV-V/FS}{UV-Visible/fluorescence spectroscopy}
\newacronym{uv-vis-spectro}{UV-VS}{UV-Visible spectroscopy}
\newacronym{fluo-spectro}{FS}{Fluorescence spectroscopy}
%\acrshort{ } ; \acrlong{ } ; \acrfull{ }
%%couleurs
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\definecolor{dark green}{RGB}{46,191,39}
%%%%maths and tikz
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%%%%units
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}}
%%%%chemistry
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
%\usepackage[en]{pgf-PeriodicTable}
%%%%boxes 
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancybox}
%table and tabular
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.17} 
%\newcolumntype{a}[1]{>{\columncolor{red!30}}l}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{#1}}
%%%%references
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{black}{\arabic{footnote}}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\textcolor{blue}{\arabic{figure}}}
%\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})} don't work
\renewcommand\thetable{\textcolor{magenta}{\arabic{table}}}
%%%%lists 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
%\newlist{notes}{enumerate}{1}
%\setlist[notes]{label=\textsl{Note:} ,leftmargin=1.4cm}
%%%%multi column
\usepackage{multicol} 
%% page style and format
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % justifie sans interligne au debut
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%%%figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=loaf,
  listname={Appendices figures},
  name=Figure,
  placement=tp,
  %within=section,% activate it if you want
  %chapterlistsgaps=on,% only meaningful when chapters exist
]{appendixfigure} %for list of figure in appendices sections
\DeclareCaptionType{appendixtable}[Table][Appendices tables] %for list of table appen.
%%%%table of contents and list of 
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%liste equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{\Large{List of equations}}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
%%condition analyse competences
\newcommand\conform{} %avec lettre => affichage, sans P n'affiche pas
\newcommand\perso[1]{
\if  
\conform P {#1}
\else{}
\fi
}
\newcommand\CONFORM{}
\newcommand\tuteur[1]{
\if  
\CONFORM T {#1}
\else{}
\fi
}
%%acknoledgements style (same as default abstract style)
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{%
  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements} % rename Abstract to Acknowledgements
  \begin{abstract}
}{%
  \end{abstract}
}
%%specifications (cahier des charges)
\newenvironment{specifications}{%
  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Specifications} 
  \begin{abstract}
}{%
  \end{abstract}
}
%%orienter 1 page en paysage
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%% appendix
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}
\newcommand{\stoptocwriting}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-5}}}
\newcommand{\resumetocwriting}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\arabic{tocdepth}}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%\nocite{*} %pour ne pas citer les ref à chaque fois
%\startcontents[sections]
%\printcontents[sections]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[scale=0.61]{../../../../../../Pictures/index.png}  \\
\begin{small}
D\'epartement Mat\'eriaux \\
Polytech Marseille, Campus Luminy \\
163 avenue de Luminy, case 925 \\
13288 Marseille Cedex 09 \\
France
\end{small}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{../lab presentations/25 mai/uppsala_university_logo.png}  \\
\vspace{-0.2em}
\begin{small}
Department of Materials Science and Engineering
\AA{}ngstr\"omlaboratoriet, Uppsala University
L\"agerhyddsv\"agen1 \\
Uppsala 75237 \\
Sweden
\end{small}
\end{flushright}
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
\vspace*{0.75cm}
\begin{center}
\shadowbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.83\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
Luminescent metal-organic frameworks for \\
the detection of volatile organic compounds 
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.25cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale=0.23]{mof example.png} 
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
stage r\'ealis\'e du 2 mai 2023 au 27 juillet 2023 \\
par Tony xxxxx \\
\'el\`eve ing\'enieur mat\'eriaux \\
$4^{\mathrm{e}}$ ann\'ee $-$ promotion 2024 
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.75cm}
\begin{flushleft}
Tuteur-Entreprise : M. xxxxx xxxxx \\
Tuteur-\'Ecole : ....
\end{flushleft}
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\begin{center}
\underline{Confidentialit\'e} \\
$ $ \\
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
Les informations contenues dans ce livrable ne pr\'esentent pas de caract\`ere confidentiel.
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{} %\tiny\insert\footins
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\begin{abstract}
text
\end{abstract}
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\centerline{\rule{9cm}{0.8pt}}
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\begin{acknowledgements}
This project was carried out from May 2023 to July 2023 and supervised by Mr. xxxxx xxxxx and Ms. xxxxx xxxxxx. The ressources, equiment and glassware used to carry out this project belong to \AA{}ngstr\"omlaboratoriet (lab of Uppsala university).
\end{acknowledgements}
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\centerline{\rule{9cm}{0.8pt}}
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Specifications}
\begin{specifications}
%\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!85!black,title=\large{Tasks to be completed}]
This project deals with synthesing and characterizing lanthanide-based \acrshort{mof}s to investigate if these materials can be used as platforms for detecting selected \acrshort{voc}s. \\
The tasks to be completed are listed below. 
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbullet]
\item Read literature on \acrshort{mof}s 
\item Plan the experimental work
\item Carry out the syntheses of different lanthanide-based \acrshort{mof}s 
\item Characterize each synthesized \acrshort{mof} (\acrshort{xrd}, \acrshort{sem}, \ldots)
\item Investigate the porosity, stability, and luminescent properties of the synthesized \acrshort{mof}s 
\end{enumerate}
%\tcblower
%text below dashed line
%\end{tcolorbox}
\end{specifications}
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{} %\tiny\insert\footins
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\section{Introduction}
text
%\newpage
%\listoffigures
%\vspace*{2.5cm}
%\listoftables
%\listofmyequations
%\newpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acronyms}
\printglossary[style=mcolindex,title=Acronyms] 
\label{acronyms}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%APPENDICES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\appendixname}
\fancyfoot[L]{} %\tiny\insert\footins
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Appendix Contents}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendices}
\appendix
\appendixpage
%\stoptocwriting
\startcontents[appendix]
\printcontents[appendix]{}{2}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\section{appendix test}
\subsection{test}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: The M in MWE stands for Minimal.

Answer (score 1):

This uses minitoc to create the TOC (`\parttoc`) for the appendices.  It uses `\addtocontents` to shut off the original table of contents in the middle of the listing.  Normally minitoc requires a `\part` command to start a `\parttoc`, but I was able to fake it using `\stepcounter{ptc}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Introduction}
Some text.

\newpage
\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}% stop listing sections

\stepcounter{ptc}% activate parttoc
\parttoc

\newpage
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, \partlof and \parlot.  You will also need \dopartlof and \doparlot (same location as \dopartoc).

Comment: If it is a formatting, let me know the specifics desired.  That part should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

The following code don't display 2 tables of contents but only one !

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\dopartlof
\dopartlot
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Introduction}
Some text.
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering 
h
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
hello & there \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{tester}
\end{table}
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}% stop listing sections

\stepcounter{ptc}% activate parttoc
\parttoc
\partlof
\partlot

\newpage
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
Some text
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering 
h
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
hello & there \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The \parttoc associated to \appendix isn't displayed as wished. How can I solve this problem ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx6lg.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz3j6.png