# Make a table of contents for appendix only (article)

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, appendix

I write an intership report with article class (because it's not that long) and I compile with pdfLatex. 
I want to display a "table of contents" which is displayed at the beginning of `\appendix` as below:

[image: whished result]

I tried something but unfortunately, all my subsections and subsubsection after `\appendix` are visible in the main table of contents at the beginning of my report. I wanted to display ONLY "Appendices" as a section in the main table of contents and let the subsection and subsubsection of `\appendix` be printed in a local table of content

[image: wished result]

Here is an extract of the code I used. I used `etoc` package and `\localtableofcontents` but it didn't work.
How can I change it ? 
Thanks

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Preamble %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[total={210mm,297mm},left=25mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% page format %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} %disable when compile periodic table
\usepackage{multicol} % multicolumn display on selected environment

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% table of contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc} %[lof,lot]
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% glossary %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[acronym,automake]{glossaries} %[automake] ou [acronym] +- ,xindy
\makeglossaries
%%%% glossary / acronyms commands documentation
%\newacronym[?key-val list?]{?label ?}{?abbrv ?}{?long?}

%\newglossaryentry{?label ?}{type=\acronymtype,
% name={?abbrv ?},
% description={?long?},
% text={?abbrv ?},
% first={?long? (?abbrv ?)},
% plural={?abbrv ?\glspluralsuffix},
% firstplural={?long?\glspluralsuffix\space (?abbrv ?\glspluralsuffix)},
% ?key-val list?}

%%%%% glossary /acronym commands
%% acronyms
\newacronym{t-14-chdca}{t-1,4-CHDCA}{trans-1,4-cyclohexane dicarboxylic acid}
\newacronym{bztca}{BzTCA}{benzene-1,3,5-tricarboxylic acid}
\newacronym{H4TBAPy}{H\textsubscript{4}TBAPy}{4,4',4'',4'''-(pyrene-1,3,6,8-tetrayl)tetrabenzoic acid}
\newacronym{d-H2O}{D H\textsubscript{2}O}{Deionized water}
\newacronym{dmf}{DMF}{Dimethylformamide}
\newacronym{h-ac}{HAc}{Acetic acid}
\newacronym{hno3}{HNO\textsubscript{3}}{Nitric acid}
\newacronym{h-acf3}{TFA}{Trifluoroacetic acid}
\newacronym{h-cl}{HCl}{Hydrochloric acid}
\newacronym{h-cooh}{HFc}{Formic acid}
\newacronym{xrd}{XRD}{X-ray diffraction}
\newacronym{pxrd}{PXRD}{Powder X-ray diffraction}
\newacronym{tga}{TGA}{Thermogravimetric analysis}
\newacronym{sem}{SEM}{Scanning electron microscopy}
\newacronym{gs}{GS}{Gas sorption}
\newacronym{uv-vis-fluo-spectro}{UV-V/FS}{UV-Visible/fluorescence spectroscopy}
\newacronym{uv-vis-spectro}{UV-VS}{UV-Visible spectroscopy}
\newacronym{fluo-spectro}{FS}{Fluorescence spectroscopy}
\newacronym{uv}{UV}{Ultraviolet}
\newacronym{ir}{IR}{Infrared}
\newacronym{nir}{NIR}{Near infrared}
%\acrshort{ } ; \acrlong{ } ; \acrfull{ }
%% glossary
\newglossaryentry{mof-gl}{name={MOF},first={Metal-organic frameworks (MOFs)},description={A metal-organic framework (MOF) is a highly crystalline porous material capable of trapping target molecules},plural={MOF\glspluralsuffix}}
\newglossaryentry{lmof-gl}{name={LMOF},description={A luminescent metal-organic framework (LMOF) is a MOF which has luminescent properties},plural={LMOF\glspluralsuffix},first={luminescent metal-organic frameworks (LMOFs)}}
\newglossaryentry{ln-mof-gl}{name={Ln-MOF},description={A lanthanide-based metal-organic framework (Ln-MOF) is a MOF with a lanthanide as cation or cluster },plural={Ln-MOF\glspluralsuffix}}
\newglossaryentry{ln-salt-gl}{name={Ln-S},description={A lanthanide salt (Ln-S) is a salt with a lanthanide as cation},plural={Ln-Sl\glspluralsuffix}}
\newglossaryentry{ln-oxide-gl}{name={Ln-Ox},description={A lanthanide oxide (Ln-Ox) is an oxide with a lanthanide as cation},plural={Ln-Oxd\glspluralsuffix}}
\newglossaryentry{voc-gl}{name={VOC},description={A volatile organic compound (VOC) is a compound that has a high vapor pressure and low water solubility},plural={VOC\glspluralsuffix},first={Volatile organic compounds (VOCs)}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% appendix %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix} %[page,header,toc]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% colors %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\definecolor{dark green}{RGB}{46,191,39} to define RGB specific color

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% maths %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% tikz & pgf %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%%% pgf
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% units %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% chemistry %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\usepackage[en]{pgf-PeriodicTable}
\usepackage{elements}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% boxes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancybox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% figures %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% environments %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{newfloat} %floating environment (such as Figure, Table, ...)
\usepackage{capt-of} %caption for non-floating environement / breakable envir.
%%% list of equations %\listofmyequations
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Equation},fileext={loe},listname={List of Equations}]{myequation}
%%% list of codes (for matlab codes) %listofcodes
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Code},fileext={loc},listname={List of Codes}]{code}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% table and tabular %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.17} 
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% references %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{Green}{\arabic{footnote}}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\textcolor{MidnightBlue}{\arabic{figure}}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\textcolor{RubineRed}{\arabic{table}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% lists %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% conditionnal writting %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\conform{} %with letter P => displayed, without P isn't displayed
\newcommand\self[1]{
\if  
\conform P {#1}
\else{}
\fi
}
\newcommand\CONFORM{}
\newcommand\supervisor[1]{
\if  
\CONFORM T {#1}
\else{}
\fi
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% acknoledgements and Specifications %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% acknowledgements
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{%
  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements} 
  \begin{abstract}
}{%
  \end{abstract}
}
%% specifications 
\newtcolorbox{specifications}[1][]{enhanced, width=0.9\textwidth ,center, colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!85!black,attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},title=\textbf{Specifications},boxed title style={colframe=blue!85!black,colback=blue!85!black},#1}
%[colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!85!black,frame hidden,width=1\linewidth,boxed title size=copy]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% landscape mode %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdflscape}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% computing in LaTeX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier} 
%code environment => see environment higher in preamble

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[scale=0.61]{../../../../../../../Pictures/index.png}    \\
\begin{small}
D\'epartement Mat\'eriaux \\
Polytech Marseille, Campus Luminy \\
163 avenue de Luminy, case 925 \\
13288 Marseille Cedex 09 \\
France
\end{small}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[scale=0.82]{../../../../../Internship materials science/My Project/project/redaction/uppsala_university_logo.png} \\
\vspace{-1.1em}
\begin{small}
Department of Materials Science and Engineering \\
\AA{}ngstr\"omlaboratoriet, Uppsala University \\
L\"agerhyddsv\"agen1 \\
Uppsala 75237 \\
Sweden
\end{small}
\end{flushright}
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{Large}
\textbf{Rapport de stage de 4\textsuperscript{e} ann\'ee} \\
\end{Large}
\smallskip
stage effectu\'e du 2 mai 2023 au 27 juillet 2023 
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.25cm}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
\shadowbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\smallskip
\begin{LARGE}
\textbf{Luminescent metal-organic frameworks for} \\
\textbf{the detection of volatile organic compounds} 
\end{LARGE}
\smallskip
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.25cm}
\begin{center}
XXXXXXXX \\
\'el\`eve-ing\'enieur mat\'eriaux \\
promotion 2024 
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.75cm}
\begin{flushleft}
Entreprise : \AA{}ngstr\"omlaboratoriet \\
\medskip
Tuteur-Entreprise : M. XXXXXXXXXXX \\
Tuteur-\'Ecole : M. XXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{flushleft}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{center}
\underline{Confidentialit\'e} \\
$ $ \\
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
Les informations contenues dans ce livrable ne pr\'esentent pas de caract\`ere confidentiel.
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{} %\tiny\insert\footins
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% table of contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
%\part{} % Start the document part
%\doparttoc % Tell to minitoc to generate a toc for the parts
%\parttoc % Insert the document TOC

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% mind map %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
$ $ \\
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color={orange!30},level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=120}, level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm},level 3/.append style={level distance=2cm}]
%, decoration={start radius=0.7cm, end radius=0.7cm,amplitude=15mm,angle=20}] to customize the link beteween the mind map nodes
%search how to use: every circle connection bar
\node{Metal-oraganic Framework}
child { node {Coordination chemistry}
    [sibling angle=120]
    child { node {Lanthanide}}
    child { node {Ligands}}
}
child { node {Characte\-rization Techniques}
    [clockwise from=120]
    child { node {PXRD}}
    child { node {TGA}}
    child { node {SEM}}
    child { node {GS}}
    child { node {Spectro\-scopy}}
}
child { node {Properties}
    [clockwise from=60]
    child { node {Crystalline}}
    child { node {Gas \&  Liquid Absorbant}}
    child { node {Lumines\-cence}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% astract, specifications and acknowlegment %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract, Acknowledgements \& Specifications}
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{abstract}
As metal-organic frameworks (MOFs) could trap water or other gases inside their pores, they could be used as a sensor to detect volatile organic compounds (VOCs) and to prevent industrial accidents. Using lanthanide-based MOFs (Ln-MOFs) could be interesting to detect VOCs because of the luminescent properties of lanthanides. To ensure that the Ln-MOFs are useful in VOCs detection, few of them will be synthesized and characterized. These Ln-MOFs contain either a ditopic or tritopic or a tetratopic linker.
\end{abstract}
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\centerline{\rule{9cm}{0.8pt}}
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\begin{acknowledgements}
I would like to thank Mr. Ocean CHEUNG and Ms. Michelle \AA{}HL\'EN for supervising my internship project from May 2023 to July 2023 and allowing me to use the ressources, equiment and glassware of \AA{}ngstr\"omlaboratoriet, the lab of Uppsala university. I would like to extend my thanks to M. Ivan ARMAND who enabled me to contact Mr Ocean CHEUNG. I want to give special dedications to Ms. Kristen ELLIOTT for taking the time to read my report so that I could correct and both my parents and my friends for their support.
\end{acknowledgements}
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\centerline{\rule{9cm}{0.8pt}}
\vspace*{0.6cm}
\begin{specifications}
This project deals with synthesing and characterizing lanthanide-based MOFs to investigate if these materials can be used as platforms for detecting selected VOCs. The tasks to be completed are listed below. 
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbullet]
\item Read literature on MOFs 
\item Plan the experimental work
\item Carry out the syntheses of different lanthanide-based MOF
\item Characterize synthesized MOF 
\item Investigate the porosity, stability, and luminescent properties of the synthesized MOFs
\end{enumerate}
\end{specifications}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% technical content %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{} %\tiny\insert\footins
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\section{Introduction}
%\acrfull{xrd}
%\acrshort{sem}
%\acrshort{gs}
%\acrshort{tga}
%\acrshort{h-ac}
%\acrshort{dmf}
%\acrshort{t-14-chdca}
%\acrshort{bztca}
%\acrshort{H4TBAPy}
%\glspl{mof-gl}
%\glspl{lmof-gl}
%\glspl{ln-mof-gl}
%\glspl{ln-salt-gl}
%\glspl{ln-oxide-gl}
%\glspl{voc-gl}
\subsection{Metal-organic frameworks}
\subsubsection{Definition}
\gls{mof-gl} are materials composed of metal nodes, such as cations or clusters, and organic ligands\footnote{see \ref*{subsec:coordianation_chem} \nameref{subsec:coordianation_chem}} named linkers. MOFs can trap molecules selectively into a pore space generated by the association of the linkers with the metal nodes \cite{MOF_chemistry}. \\
$ $ \\
MOFs are highly crystalline and porous. There absorption selectivity is based on the pores size, shape, polarity and chemical interaction with target molecules. Knowing that, controlling the parameters of the pores allows the selectivity of the absorbed species to be modified. Absorbed species can be released by increasing the temperature or decreasing the pressure \cite{MOF_chemistry}. 
\subsubsection{Luminescent properties}
\gls{voc-gl}, such as \acrshort{dmf}, can be absorbed by \glspl{mof-gl} which have \ch{Eu^{3+}} or \ch{Tb^{3+}} as metal nodes. These metals have interresting luminescent properties: their luminescence can be detected with eyes. Indeed, the light emitted by \ch{Eu^{3+}} after interaction with target compound is red and that emitted by \ch{Tb^{3+}} is green \cite{MOF_fluorescence}. These \glspl{mof-gl} are categorized as luminescent. Overall, \gls{lmof-gl} have a luminescence from \acrshort{uv} to \acrshort{nir} \cite{MOF_luminescence}.
\subsection{Coordination chemistry} 
    \label{subsec:coordianation_chem}

\subsection{Synthesis process}
\gls{mof-gl} are synthesized using a solvothermal process. 
\subsection{Characterization techniques}
\section{Experimental data analysis}
\subsection{Coordination complexes made from \acrshort{t-14-chdca}}
\subsubsection{\acrshort{pxrd}}
\subsubsection{\acrshort{tga}}
\subsection{Coordination complexes made from \acrshort{bztca}}
\subsubsection{\acrshort{pxrd}}
\subsubsection{\acrshort{tga}}
\subsection{Coordination complexes made from \acrshort{H4TBAPy}}
\subsubsection{\acrshort{pxrd}}
\subsubsection{\acrshort{tga}}
%%%%%%%% lists of figures, tables, ... %%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{} %\tiny\insert\footins
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lists: Figures, Tables, Equations, Codes}
%\partlof
\vspace{1.5cm}
\listoftables
%\partlot
\vspace{1.5cm}
\listofmyequations
\vspace{1.5cm}
\listofcodes

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% references and glossaries %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References \& Acronyms}
\bibliographystyle{plainurl} %plain ou ieeetr
\bibliography{internship_bibliog} 
\href{https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WSbzuMsPWjR5oHr_vnaTJbNMn8kSM4sd?usp=drive_link}{\faDownload \hspace{0.3cm} Download the report bibliography as a Bib\LaTeX \: file (.bib)}
\vspace{0.5cm}
%\printglossaries
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype ,title={Acronyms}]
\printglossary[type=main ,title={Glossary}]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% APPENDICES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\appendix
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\appendixpage %print appendices as part title without "part I"
\renewcommand\thesubsection{A.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{A.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
%don't work because of babel package --> addto captions english command
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My nice list of figures}
%\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{My nice list of figures}
%\renewcommand{\listtablename}{My nice list of table}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Appendix Figures}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Appendix Tables}}
\vspace{0.5cm}
%\centerline{\rule{9cm}{0.8pt}}
%\vspace{0.5cm}
\localtableofcontents
%\vspace{1.5cm}
%\locallistoffigures
%\vspace{1.5cm}
%\locallistoftables
\newpage
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
%\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{Appendices}
%\addcontentsline{lot}{section}{Appendices}
%\addcontentsline{loe}{section}{Appendices}
%\addcontentsline{loc}{section}{Appendices}
\subsection{Solvothermal process}
\subsubsection{Definition}
A solvothermal process is a chemical reaction that occurs in a organic solvent at a temperature above than its boiling point in a sealed vessel. 
\subsubsection{Parameters}
text
\subsection{\acrfull{xrd}}
    \label{appendix-subsec:XRD}
\subsubsection{Principles of \acrshort{xrd}}

\subsubsection{\acrshort{xrd} software}

\subsection{\acrfull{sem}}
    \label{appendix-subsec:SEM}
\subsubsection{Secondary and backscattered electron images}

\subsubsection{EDS} 

\subsection{\acrfull{tga}} 
    \label{appendix-subsec:TGA}
\subsubsection{Principle of thermogravimetric analysis}
text
\subsubsection{TGA computations}

\subsection{\acrfull{uv-vis-fluo-spectro}}
\subsubsection{\acrfull{uv-vis-spectro}}
text
\subsubsection{\acrfull{fluo-spectro}}
text

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% supervisor evaluations %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\supervisor{
text
}
\self{
text
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686939/make-a-table-of-contents-specific-to-appendix-article-class-and-display-appen  In fact, it was your question.

Comment: I know that I asked the same thing before but the given solutions didn't work as I wished. That's why I'm open for other solutions !

Comment: Your posted example becomes basically useless as it shows absolutely no effort to reduce it to what is relevant to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be explained in `etoc` documentation, simply from looking at its table of contents, there is a `Part III Control of contents`, section `19. The \etocdepthtag.toc`, and this section starts with *The command \etocdepthtag.toc allows to control dynamically the which contents end up included in the displayed TOCs*.

So, applying the method here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
% Kept from posted original humongous example containing zillions of irrelevant things which cost 15 minutes of senseless workload to trim out
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix} %[page,header,toc]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\etocsettagdepth{appendix}{section}% only print the Appendices entry not its
                                % subsections in main TOC
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Metal-organic frameworks}
\subsubsection{Definition}
\subsection{Coordination chemistry} 

\subsection{Synthesis process}
\subsection{Characterization techniques}
\section{Experimental data analysis}
\subsection{Coordination complexes made from t-14-chdca}
\subsubsection{pxrd}
\subsubsection{tga}
\subsection{Coordination complexes made from {bztca}}
\subsubsection{{pxrd}}
\subsubsection{{tga}}
\subsection{Coordination complexes made from {H4TBAPy}}
\subsubsection{{pxrd}}
\subsubsection{{tga}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% APPENDICES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\appendix

\etocdepthtag.toc{appendix}% nota bene: the .toc file entry "Appendices" will
                           % originate from \appendixpage, so the depth tag
                           % will end up being located in .toc file before it
                           % we could permute the two, but one has to know
                           % which one comes first to well use
                           % \etocsettagdepth command for main \tableofcontents

\appendixpage %print appendices as part title without "part I"
\renewcommand\thesubsection{A.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{A.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\etocignoredepthtags % ignore the instruction to not include subsections in
                     % TOC which must apply only to main TOC, not this one
\localtableofcontents
\newpage
\subsection{Solvothermal process}
\subsubsection{Definition}
A solvothermal process is a chemical reaction that occurs in a organic solvent at a temperature above than its boiling point in a sealed vessel. 
\subsubsection{Parameters}
text
\subsection{xrd}
\subsubsection{Secondary and backscattered electron images}

\subsubsection{EDS} 
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: table of contents]

as main TOC without changing anything to the local table of contents for Appendices.