# How to generate a partial Table of content in Overleaf?

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I have been struggling to find a way to generate a partial "table of content" in overleaf. Let's say that in my manuscript i have a global table of content with all chapters, sections and subsections. This works perfectly.
But i want to generate a table of content inside each chapters. For example : I want in chapter 1 a table of content for the sections and subsections related to chapter 1 only. Same for chapter 2 and so on. for some reason i can't find the code to personalize the \tableofcontents command. Maybe there is an other one i should use i don't know. Maybe it is impossible :(

If it helps you can see below the parameters of my document. And also, maybe it is relevant, i have separated each chapters in a .tex file , separate from my main .tex file.

thank you for your help,

I am not familiar with programming so i have tried whatever answer chatgpt could give me. The overleaf manuel doesn't seem to explore this question.
The most promising solution was to create a new command but i think that it is in conflict with the existing command of table of content. Not sure how to dissociate the two.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{helvet} % Pretty font
\usepackage[default,osf]{raleway} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel} % Last language, language by default
\usepackage{graphicx,enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=RoyalBlue4]{hyperref}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand{\Gray}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
\parindent 0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This isn't actually an Overleaf or LaTeX3 issue, so those aren't quite the right tags.  I see that you've loaded `minitoc`.  Have you looked at its [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc?lang=en)?  That does what you're asking for.  I think the `etoc` package could also do what you want.

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686939/make-a-table-of-contents-specific-to-appendix-article-class-and-display-appen/686973?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#686973 useful.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will check this out

Comment: @T.victor Please stop adding the latex3 tag. Your code does not seem to contain any latex3 code.